# Angular user authentication in MEAN

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I am newbie in MEAN. I am handle authentication at server side by using `express-session`. But i want implement authentication at Angular that is when user hit url and if session expired then it automatically redirect to `login` page. I am using `UI-Route($stateProvider)` for handle route. Here is my code snippet:-

Server side:-

```
//server.js
....
function isAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
    if (req.session.isLoggedIn)
        return next();
    else {
        res.clearCookie("isLoggedIn");
        res.status(403).end('Session expired please login again.');
    }
}
....
```

Front-end side:-

```
.....
$stateProvider.
    state('app', {
        url: '/app',
        templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
        controller:'homeCtrl'
    }).
    state('app.maindashboard', {
         url: '/maindashboard',
        templateUrl: 'views/maindashboard.html',
        controller:'maindashboardCtrl'
    })

....
```

Comment: I'd store the session in frontend and check against that

Comment: Maybe read the cookie everytime the angular application starts and set a timeout for refresh.